# CXF- client giving "java.lang.VerifyError: Cannot inherit from final class"

Tags: java, web-services, cxf

Hi i am using the following code to call a cxf service and getting the error. how to resolve this?

```
WebClient client = WebClient.create("http://localhost:8080/weath/api/v1/cities/cities", "test", "murali", null);
```

The above code is giving this error:-

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.VerifyError: Cannot inherit from final class
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:455)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:367)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
at org.ymd.CxfClient.main(CxfClient.java:29)
```

All the jars that i have in my classpath are:-

- cxf-rt-rs-client-3.1.7.jar
- cxf-rt-transports-http-hc-3.1.7.jar
- cxf-bundle-jaxrs-2.1.2.jar
- cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs-3.1.7.jar
- cxf-core-3.1.7.jar
- cxf-rt-transports-http-3.1.7.jar
- javax.persistence-2.1.1.jar
  -cxf-api-2.7.18.jar
- javax.ws.rs-api-2.0.jar

Comment: Is the error occurring in your development environment or when deployed on a server?

Comment: on my development machine i have used a standardalone class which have main method int it. inside that main method i am calling that service. service is running on local machines tomcat on port 8080.

Comment: Could  be a version mismatch between what is in  your IDE/standalone class and what is deployed in Tomcat. Make sure the same versions are installed both places.

Comment: I am using "cxf 3.1.x"  along with jre8 on server and the same i am using to write my client.

Comment: Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved my problem. it is because of version conflict. When i use maven for getting dependencies everything got resolved.